# How to do Left JOIN with ORDER and LIMIT MySql

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a sql that pulls tickets and I need to left join it with last reply time and last reply by

but this sql is still pulling multiple replies for 1 ticket and I need only last one

```
SELECT a.*,
r.lastreply_by,
r.lastreplytime
FROM  `tickets` AS a
LEFT JOIN replies AS r ON a.id = (SELECT r.ticketid ORDER BY ticketid DESC LIMIT 1)
```

here is snap from that sql 
http://prntscr.com/2b4ihy

any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: you don't check the codition which combines the both table. what's the common column for both table?

Comment: I am joiing the tables on id = ticketid , you can see it from snapshot i posted

Comment: why do you use left join? you want datas for the last ticketid?

Comment: no I need data from each ticket joined with last replyby and lastreplytime

Comment: Take a look at some top-rated questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.*,
r.lastreply_by,
r.lastreplytime
FROM  `tickets` AS a
LEFT JOIN replies AS r
ON r.id = (
  SELECT r2.id
  FROM replies r2
  WHERE r2.ticketid = a.id
  ORDER BY r2.lastreplytime DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Edit: I changed the order by to `lastreplytime` so it in fact returns the latest reply.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f5c16/4

Comment: ticket_id = ticketid but this one works,  I am not sure wich one is more effective but this one seems simple

Comment: I actually had another error in my original code: it should be `order by r2.lastreplytime`.

Comment: no ticketid order is fine since they are created in order so BY r2.ticketid  works great. thank you!

Comment: With regards to performance: MySQL doesn't use any indices if you select from subqueries, so in Sebas' answer the join cannot use a key on `t.t` and in Peterm's  answer the group by cannot use a key on `q.ticketid` nor can the join use a key on `r.ticketid`. So I would expect my answer to run fastest in most cases, but this depends on the actual data and defined indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way

```
SELECT t.*,
       r.lastreply_by,
       r.lastreplytime
  FROM tickets t LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT ticketid, lastreply_by, lastreplytime
      FROM
    (
        SELECT ticketid, lastreply_by, lastreplytime
          FROM replies 
         ORDER BY lastreplytime DESC
    ) q
     GROUP BY ticketid
) r
    ON t.id = r.ticketid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9c23f6/2)** demo

Comment: thank you much , performance vise which one is more efficient , yours or  the one from unique2 ? I have chosen the unique as top answer since it is just continuing on my sql and it "looks" simpler

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `replyid` is the unique key per reply in the `replies` table:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    r.lastreply_by,
    r.lastreplytime
FROM  
    `tickets` a
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ticketid t, MAX(replyid) replyid
            FROM
                replies
            GROUP BY ticketid
        ) t ON t.t = a.ticketid
        LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.ticketid = t.t AND r.replyid = t.replyid
```

ps: this is standard SQL, so it provides a good alternative to peter's answer (that does not make it less valid of course).